# ptrace returning -1 on Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, gdb, ptrace

I'm trying to detect when gdb is attached to my app and I'm using this in JNI code

```
long x = ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 1, 0);    
char buffer[24];
sprintf(buffer, "ptrace = %ld", x);
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buffer);
```

However, `x` is always `-1` regardless of whether gdb is attached or not. Why is that? What can I do to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hello Mirza, if your goal is to solely detect if a debugger is attached, have a look at slides 45-55 of the following presentation https://bluebox.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/AndroidREnDefenses201305.pdf. As for the ptrace issue, if have no idea why your result is always -1. The ptrace implementation of ARM Linux is different, probably the call you make is also affected in some way.

Comment: @jmeinke I've seen that article but that code is for detecting the Java debugger in native code. Also, I don't think DvmGlobals is available in ART anymore. What I was hoping to do is prevent gdb from attaching.

Comment: Ever tried `perror("");` or something?

Comment: late to the party, but have you given root to the app since ptrace need root permission [reference](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace#Uses)